How can I debug a Perl module during initialization in VSCode?
I'm using VSCode connected to a remote (local network) SSH instance running on Linux, which has the Language Server and Debug Protocol Adapter for Perl installed.
It's easy enough to add breakpoints to a script, for example:
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# test.pl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Types;

use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper $Types::Error;

and debug what's happening during the execution of the script, but what if I want to debug a module loaded by the script itself (specifically the module Types in the example, which performs some self-initialization - basically, a foreach loop at the end of the module)?
Adding a breakpoint to the module:

and running test.pl in the debugger won't work as the foreach loop is run before test.pl is run.
So how may I go about debugging what's happening in Types before the module is loaded into the script?

Your script use (import) type, but does nothing with it. Maybe you could start by really process something with the Type module so that the debugger would pass through it.  E.g. what you did with Data::Dumper: it's actually used only when you call the Dumper() function, not when you import the module with use.

@smonff My understanding has always been that under the hood a module would still be evaluated even if I don't do anything with it (am I wrong?), however I tried just in case to print a package-scoped variable (Error - see the updated script), the debugger still doesn't stop at that breakpoint.

What happens if you add a sub foo { print 'hello' ;} in Types.pm, put a breakpoint on the print call, and call it in your script with Types::foo(); ?

Not sure because I have a very partial view of your code, but your breakpoint is right after a return statement. So maybe set the breakpoint at line 123.

Also, in case the %test_functions_to_declare hash is empty, you won't be able to iterate on it's keys, etc. so your breakpoint won't be taken into account.

@smonff I don't have to try that, I know that would work and that I would be able to debug foo's scope (I've had to do this a lot of times when debugging functions exported by module), the problem is that I want to debug the initializazion phase. Granted, I could wrap the initialization in a sub a work around the problem like that but changing how the code is structured doesn't really feel like a solution... The return you're mentioning is inside an eval statement which basically declares a function, so no returning is done there.

@smonff test_functions_to_declare is indeed populated, however even moving the breakpoint to line 118 doesn't make the debugger stop in Types. I think the debugger overall just doesn't latch to external modules before executing the main script itself

Add $DB::single = 1; to where you want to break

If that doesn't work, replaces use Types; with require Types; import Types; (Same thing, but at run-time.)

@smonff Sorry, I couldn't join before, but again thanks for the effort and spending time on this. ikegami got it, I didn't think this was related to the debugger itself, apparently it is and I was doing it the wrong way. Thanks again!

@ikegami $DB::single = 1; did the trick, thank you!
